# Configuring my function app for checking log in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

I create a durable function and need to see the log using App Insights, I configured my Host.json but I saw a lot of logs in App Insight, How can I delimit the logs, just show the log defined in my own function?

Answer (score 0):

To see just your own logging messages, that were logged via the `ILogger` injected into the function, you can query the Application Insights Logs like this:

```
traces
| where customDimensions["Category"] endswith ".User"
```

*If* you are also logging out from other classes that take an `ILogger<T>`, then you can also include those with additional clauses on customDimensions["Category"].

e.g. if your code has a root namespace of "AcmeCompany":

```
traces
| where customDimensions["Category"] endswith ".User"
 or (customDimensions["Category"] startswith "AcmeCompany")
```

Comment: {
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Function.FunctionNAME": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}

Comment: I tried to put in Host.json that, the logs in app insight are much, I just show logs handling in the function using ILogger

Thanks